# Как в миграции Yii запустить метод из существующего контроллера?

Tags: php, yii

В миграции я создаю новые поля. После создания полей мне необходимо запустить метод (который лежит в Контроллере), который с определенным условием выполняет расчеты по базе и складывает полученные значение в только что созданные поля.
Как мне такой метод запустить в миграции?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вынести необходимые действия из контроллера в свой компонент и в дальнейшем использовать его в контроллере и миграции.

Answer (score 3):

Long story short: у вас порядочные проблемы с архитектурой, вы **не** должны запускать методы в миграциях, вы **не** должны обновлять содержимое БД в миграциях, приложение **не** должно запрашивать контроллер напрямую.

Short story long:

#### FSUC

Первая проблема, про которую следует рассказать - это так называемые толстые тупые контроллеры. Это выражение подразумевает под собой контроллер, в который зашита вся бизнес-логика приложения для одного действия. Это в корне неправильно как раз из-за вышеописанной ситуации - контроллер является **точкой входа** и ничем более, и если он начинает вбирать в себя логику, то эту логику прямым путем уже никак не вызвать. Поэтому контроллер должен состоять из минимального количество строк, формируя объект ввода и тут же передавая его в *сервис*. В рамках Yii сервис будет называться компонентом.

#### Изменение данных в базе во время применения миграции

Миграции - это инструмент для версионирования **структуры** базы данных. В них никогда не должно быть реальных данных и DML-запросов, кроме UPDATE-запросов, производящих инициализацию полей, готовящихся принять ограничение not null. В миграциях не должно быть никакой инициализации данных, они для этого не предназначены, и их обратимость в этом случае вызывает большие вопросы.

#### Запуск стороннего функционала внутри миграции

Это - очередной noooo. Ровно как модульные тесты не должны иметь много ассертов, сложных сценариев, циклов и вызовов дополнительного функционала, так и результат миграций всегда должен быть детерминированным, каждая миграция должна быть максимально атомарной, и лишь описывать внедряемые изменения. Это - залог здоровой системы, гарантия того, что если что-то и пойдет не так, то это сможет исправить любой в сжатые сроки, и это не заденет соседний код, вызывая эффект домино.

#### Preseed

В случае, если вам нужно заполнять БД изначальными данными, вам нужна отдельный компонент для этого, который будет обернут в консольную команду. В идеале, если у вас есть функционал заполнения готовыми данными и функционал расчета других данных, то это должны быть два компонента с двумя консольными командами.
После всего этого никто не мешает написать еще одну консольную команду, которая просто объединит все вышеописанное.

#### Why so matters

Почему это так важно? Потому что это минимальный набор, необходимый для поддержания тенического долга на разумном уровне. Пока у вас команда дергает контроллер который дергает функционал, никто - вообще никто, кроме написавшего этого программиста, да и то в первый месяц - не знает, что там внутри. Любой чих по изменению код (а он будет, поверьте) обернется дичайшим геморроем и поломкой совместимости, и хорошо, если на этот функционал есть интеграционные тесты, которые вовремя найдут проблему.